# Телеграм-бот не останавливается

Tags: python, aiogram

Проблема следующая, после нажатия Ctrl+C, в терминале выводится следующее сообщение

```
INFO:aiogram.dispatcher.dispatcher:Stop polling...
WARNING:aiogram:Goodbye!
```

И дальнейшая работа с терминалом не является возможной, поскольку на этом сообщении он и зависает

Код который запускает бота

```
#bot.py
import asyncio
import datetime

import Scheduler
from aiogram import executor
from dispatcher import dp
from db import BotDB
import handlers

db = BotDB("Help_For_Tutors.db")


async def send_scheduled_message_lesson():
    while True:
        await db.connect()
        await Scheduler.send_message_lesson()
        await asyncio.sleep(60)
        


async def send_scheduled_message_lesson_status():
    while True:
        await db.connect()
        await Scheduler.send_message_lesson_status()
        await asyncio.sleep(30*60)



async def duplication():
    while True:
        await db.connect()
        await Scheduler.make_duplicates()
        await asyncio.sleep(30*60)


async def send_scheduled_subscription_reminders():
    while True:
        await db.connect()
        await Scheduler.send_subscription_reminders()
        await asyncio.sleep(86400)



async def add_class():
    today = datetime.datetime.now()
    today_str = today.strftime("%m-%d")
    while True:
        await db.connect()
        if today_str == "08-30":
            await Scheduler.update_class()
            await asyncio.sleep(86400)
        else:
            await asyncio.sleep(86400)



async def on_startup(dp):
    asyncio.create_task(send_scheduled_message_lesson())
    asyncio.create_task(send_scheduled_message_lesson_status())
    asyncio.create_task(duplication())
    asyncio.create_task(add_class())
    # asyncio.create_task(send_scheduled_subscription_reminders())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, on_startup=on_startup, skip_updates=True)


#dispatcher.py
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
import config
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# prerequisites
if not config.BOT_TOKEN:
    exit("No token provided")

# init
storage = MemoryStorage()
bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN, parse_mode="HTML")
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)
```

Конструкцию подобного плана не предлагайте

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        executor.start_polling(dp, on_startup=on_startup, skip_updates=True)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Bot has been interrupted. Exiting...")
```

Я уже пробовал ее, она не помогает

Comment: Может с терминалом проблемы? Лично у меня такой проблемы никогда не было. Попробуйте вместо cmd использовать powershell, к примеру, или наоборот.

Answer (score 0):

Комбинация клавиш `Ctrl-C` в терминале обрывает выполнение программы. Чтобы вставить что-нибудь, вам придется пользоваться правой кнопкой мыши.

Comment: Ну так ТС и хочет оборвать выполнение программы.